# Can't Edit/Update Certain Items In Database (Table)

Tags: google-app-maker

I have database that I have multiple orders entered into. Everything seems to be working fine except for a few old entries which will not accept updates/changes to their Fields.

Note: The majority of the Fields are Strings with Possible Values entered via a DropDown Box.

So if I open **Order A** I can make adjustments just fine and those changes persist even after closing the page and coming back or refreshing.

But if I open Order B, I can make changes via the dropdowns and it looks like they have adjusted, however if I leave the page or refresh all the changes have reverted back.

One piece of info that may be helpful is that each of these orders has at least one Field that contains an entry that is **no longer a Possible Value** (the original entries were removed/changed per request of the client).

Maybe they are "locked" because of this? Is there a way to look at an error log for a Published app?

I can delete the "corrupt" entries and recreate them (since there are currently only a few), but I would prefer to find a better solution in case this happens again in the future.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. Such field level value updates should get through.

As workaround you can update prohibited(not possible anymore) values with allowed ones in OnSave Model's Event like:

```js
switch (record.Field) {
  case "old_value_1":
    record.Field = "new_value_1";
    break;
  case "old_value_2":
    record.Field = "new_value_2";
    break;
  ...
}
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Each deployment has its own log. Have you tried "App Settings > DEPLOYMENTS > (click on the desployment) > VIEW LOGS"?